# wordpress website- implement search sort and filter

Tags: wordpress, web, search, filter

i am using avada fusion theme in my wordpress site, different plugins work fine if i need to search posts and pages, but i need to search/sort/filter in a page where i have created 100+ containers/items as a list(like slides or templates).
how can i get it done?

And also what would be a good approach if my list is going to be long i.e 400+ in near future?
re: i have different graphical and text included items in a page with same templates, and i need to search, sort, filter from that list in that page.

I do not see any option to tag or id each template/containers in page which would make search/sort easy.

thank you in advance

Comment: hi bro. i think its better to ask this question in [stackexchange wordpress](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: sure, thank you will do that.